# How to extend Laravel's Auth Guard class?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, extending

I'm trying to extend Laravel's Auth [Guard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php) class by one additional method, so I'm able to call `Auth::myCustomMethod()` at the end.

Following the documentation section [Extending The Framework](http://laravel.com/docs/extending) I'm stuck on how to exactly do this because the Guard class itself doesn't have an own [IoC binding](http://laravel.com/docs/facades#facade-class-reference) which I could override.

Here is some code demonstrating what I'm trying to do:

```
namespace Foobar\Extensions\Auth;

class Guard extends \Illuminate\Auth\Guard {

    public function myCustomMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Now how should I register the extended class `Foobar\Extensions\Auth\Guard` to be used instead of the original `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` so I'm able to call `Auth::myCustomMethod()` the same way as e.g. `Auth::check()`?

One way would be to replace the `Auth` alias in the `app/config/app.php` but I'm not sure if this is really the best way to solve this.

BTW: I'm using Laravel 4.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would create my own UserProvider service that contain the methods I want and then extend Auth.

I recommend creating your own service provider, or straight up extending the Auth class in one of the start files (eg. `start/global.php`).

```
Auth::extend('nonDescriptAuth', function()
{
    return new Guard(
        new NonDescriptUserProvider(),
        App::make('session.store')
    );
});
```

This is a good [tutorial you can follow to get a better understanding](http://www.karlvalentin.de/1903/write-your-own-auth-driver-for-laravel-4.html)

There is another method you could use. It would involve extending one of the current providers such as Eloquent.

```
class MyProvider extends Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider {

    public function myCustomMethod()
    {
        // Does something 'Authy'
    }
}
```

Then you could just extend auth as above but with your custom provider.

```
\Auth::extend('nonDescriptAuth', function()
{
    return new \Illuminate\Auth\Guard(
        new MyProvider(
            new \Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher,
            \Config::get('auth.model')
        ),
        \App::make('session.store')
    );
});
```

Once you've implemented the code you would change the driver in the `auth.php` config file to use 'nonDescriptAuth`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David! I was hoping there is a simpler method than creating a own UserProvider to extend the Guard class. I will wait some time to see if there are other suggestions.

Comment: @HolgerWeis I've added in a simple method to extend Auth with the current Eloquent driver with an extension. The `Auth::extend` code should work as is.

Answer (score -7):

Only way to add (and also replace existing functions) is to create copy of **Guard.php** file in your project and in **app/start/global.php** add:

```
require app_path().'/models/Guard.php';
```

Of course it's ugly method, but I spent over hour to test all possibilities [how to change things stored in Session by Auth] and it always end with error:
... _contruct of class HSGuard requires first parameter to be 'UserProviderInterface' and get 'EloquentUserProvider' ...